# Resignation letter and notice period

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I am currently unhappy in my company and I am considering to leave it. 
I might be offered a new position next days, but I don't know what the resignation letter should mention.

Even if I don't have an offer I would like to start giving notice, but what happens if in the middle of my notice period I find a new company that wants me straight away?

As from my contract I should give 3 months notice, but when discussed they say we can settle down if something comes out for me.

What I am concerned about is, what should I write in the letter? If I write that I will be working for them for other three months am I then obliged to do that or we can discuss it again? Will I be legally obliged?

What should be written in a resignation letter?

Comment: Did you Google your last line "What should be written in a resignation letter?"

Comment: Three months notice... lol... I wonder if they would give you three months notice when they are done with you.

Answer (score 2):

Typically all you have to do is state that you are resigning effective the date that equates to the contractual obligation for notice you have. So today's letter would state:

Effective April 23, 2015, I am resigning my position.

You can be polite and state that you learned a lot and wish them well in the future, but really all you need is one sentence with the expected termination date. If you want to leave earlier through paying something to get out of the contract (based on your contract rules, you might add a sentence stating you would like to discuss the possibility of leaving on an earlier date.

You are under no obligation to tell them why you are resigning or where you are going or what your new salary will be.

If someone makes you an offer in the meantime, tell them you have a contractual obligation until this date, but you will see if you can get it moved up. You could talk to your boss at this point and see if he is willing to let you go early, but if he isn't, then you have a contractual obligation and can't accept the other job without legal consequences. So it is often best to tell the new job, the date you are stuck with. A decent company will appreciate that you honor your obligations.